How to remove package with dependencies in APT?
I wish to keep my system clean, and I write out which packages were installed so that I can remove them later. But dependencies remain sometimes.
I installed the libasound2-plugin-equal package and it also pulled in caps. I removed libasound2-plugin-equal, but apt did not remove caps.
root@devuan:~# apt install libasound2-plugin-equal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  caps
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  caps libasound2-plugin-equal
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 230 kB of archives.
After this operation, 632 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus/main amd64 caps amd64 0.9.26-1 [215 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus/main amd64 libasound2-plugin-equal amd64 0.6-8 [14.9 kB]
Fetched 230 kB in 1s (211 kB/s)               
Selecting previously unselected package caps.
(Reading database ... 268554 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../caps_0.9.26-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking caps (0.9.26-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libasound2-plugin-equal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libasound2-plugin-equal_0.6-8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasound2-plugin-equal:amd64 (0.6-8) ...
Setting up caps (0.9.26-1) ...
Setting up libasound2-plugin-equal:amd64 (0.6-8) ...
root@devuan:~# 
root@devuan:~# 
root@devuan:~# apt remove libasound2-plugin-equal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libasound2-plugin-equal
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 72.7 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 268570 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libasound2-plugin-equal:amd64 (0.6-8) ...
root@devuan:~# 
root@devuan:~# 
root@devuan:~# apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@devuan:~# 

autoremove does not help. Why does autoremove not react here given that the caps package was installed as a dependency?

This happens because some other package on your system depends (weakly) on caps, or the virtual ladspa-plugin package it provides. apt autoremove only removes packages which are absolutely not depended upon by anything in any way; see How do recommends and suggests interact with apt-get dist-upgrade and apt-get autoremove? for details.
If you install aptitude, you can use that to find out what’s keeping caps:
aptitude why caps

To answer your actual question, the best way to remove caps is to do so manually:
apt purge caps

You could configure apt autoremove to ignore recommended and suggested packages, but that would remove far more packages than you’d probably want.
See also why this package is not proposed to me to remove?
